# Python real time screen processing

Tags: python, real-time, ocr

I would like to process my screen in a real time. 
Is there some real time OCR library for python, that I could use? 
Or is there some better technology that I could use?

Comment: What do you mean by "process my screen" ? Do you want to make a screenshot of the desktop ? or The command line ?

Comment: Are you asking for help with *capturing* the screen, or *processing* the captured image to do Optical Charatcer Recognition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VLC, go to Media -> Stream -> Capture Device, select Desktop and create the stream. Create a HTTP stream.

Then use OpenCV to open the stream and use something like this:

```
cv::VideoCapture vcap;
if(!vcap.open(videoStreamAddress)) {
    std::cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
cv::namedWindow("Output Window");

while (true) {
    if(!vcap.read(image)) {
        std::cout << "No frame" << std::endl;
        cv::waitKey();
    }
    //Process image here
}
```

Sorry it's C++ not Python but you can do the same thing in Python easily.

Disclaimer: I have not tested this myself, it is just an idea